# load UIWebView - NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

How can I load a uiwebview with nsdata like if have

```
 NSData *da = [[NSData alloc]initwithContentsofURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]; //not tested
```

and now use this NSData in UIWebView.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this method

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

in the UIWebView documentation.  That should allow you to load the data in the web view.

Comment: what would be MIMEType? I mean what would we put as a parameter for that?

Comment: so I have another question now if i send the data of this nsdata to another device via blutetooh will the webpage still load from the recieving device

Comment: It is possible.  You would have to have an app that would process that data on the receiving device.

Comment: what if there is no internet sorry I don't have 2 iphones

Comment: You will need an Internet connection because you need to download the data.